# How to know if the actual cell has border top in

Tags: c#, excel, parsing, interop, cell

I need to check in a worksheet if each given cell has BORDER TOP of any type and if the cell is empty

This is what i have done so far...

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(original_file_path + file_name + xls);

//Work on sheet number 2
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet x = workbook.Worksheets[2];

INT MAX_ROW = usedRange.Rows.Count;
INT MAX_COL = usedRange.Columns.Count;

for (int row = 1; row <= MAX_ROW; row++)
{
 for (int col = 1; col <= MAX_COL; col++)
 {
//The following line is pseudocode since i have no idea how to use border property. This checks if the given cell is empty and if the border top is null
   if(x.Cells[row,col].Borders.topBorder == false && x.Cells[row,col].Value == null)
   {
   //The thing that i want to do with this is replace that cell value to the one located on Cells [row -1, col]
     x.Cells[row,col].value = x.Cells[row -1, col].value;
   }else {
   Console.WriteLine("nothing to do here");
   }

 }
}
```

Comment: Related Question (but not the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58547106/c-sharp-excel-interop-how-to-check-if-a-single-cell-in-a-range-has-cell-borde

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick method you can adapt to your liking that should give you the logic you need...  in effect, I am just looking at the line style of the cell's top border.  If it's "none," then the other properties don't really matter.

You were on the right track, but `Borders` is an indexer, and you feed it the border in question and evaluate the LineStyle property.

```
private bool HasTopBorder(Excel.Range r)
{
    return ((Excel.XlLineStyle)r.Borders[Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeTop].LineStyle) !=
        Excel.XlLineStyle.xlLineStyleNone;
}
```

Interestingly, `LineStyle` returns an integer, hence the cast.  This means you can simply figure out what the enum for `xlLineStyleNone` is and make that comparison, but whatever you gain in efficiency you will lose more in transparency.

And again, inline this if it makes sense within your code, but I wanted to isolate the logic you needed.